# Problem with pass dump into database (postgresql) terminal doesnt show errors

Tags: postgresql, backup, dump

I'm trying to pass dump into database as same as always do.
But now It's not working, and I haven't any idea what could happend...
So from start point:
I create brand new database:

```
sudo psql -U postgres
drop database db_name; create database db_name; grant all privileges on database db_name to user; grant all privileges on database db_name to user2;
```

For this moment everything is working.
But now If i do this:

```
sudo psql -U postgres db_name < dump-25-05-2020.sql
```

terminal show me nothing, any errors, logs nothing.
This dump is working, I'm using it everyday (even today)
My os is MacOS Catalina the latest version.

How can I run this command with logs or something which show me what is going on?

Comment: What is [```client_min_messages```](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-CLIENT-MIN-MESSAGES) set to in postgresql.conf? You can also tail the Postgres server log  to see what is going on.

Comment: I passed this dump into database today and everything was okay. So on passing dump into database I have all logs in my terminal like alters, contraints, indexing etc. But now nothing shows. I pass the password to pstgres user and commands end without any log and errors

Comment: And of course the data was not migrate from dum to the database

Comment: Just noticed this ```sudo psql```. Should this not be ```sudo  -u postgres psql```? Also what is ```client_min_messages``` set to?

Comment: @up Nope, this command was working correctly everytime

Comment: client_min_messages how can i set this on higher lvl?

Comment: Read the docs at the link I sent in my first comment. What happens if you include the full path to psql in the command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218460/discussion-between-programmer-and-adrian-klaver).